# Issue with multi dimensional becoming empty after assigning to var

Tags: javascript

I'm having a very strange issue with javascript where I'm building a multi dimensional array and somehow it's being emptied to `[[]]` on var assignment.
The target being passed to the buildFormObject function is a html form element.

```js
if (!Element.prototype.closest) {
    Element.prototype.closest = function(s) {
        var el = this;
        if (!document.documentElement.contains(el)) return null;
        do {
            if (el.matches(s)) return el;
            el = el.parentElement || el.parentNode;
        } while (el !== null && el.nodeType === 1);
        return null;
    };
}

var submit = document.getElementsByClassName('submit');
submitForm_click(submit);

function submitForm_click (trigger) {
  if (trigger.length > 0) {
    for (var t of trigger) {
      t.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        submitForm(t.parentNode);
      });
    }
  } else {
    trigger.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      submitForm(trigger.parentNode);
    });
  }
}

function submitForm (target) {
  var info = buildFormObject(target);
  console.log(buildFormObject(target));
  console.log(info);
}
  
function buildFormObject (target) {
var inputs = target.querySelectorAll('input,select');
var results = [];
var multi = [];
var iter = 0;
var pos = 0;
for (var input of inputs) {
  if (iter > 0) {
    iter = iter - 1;
    continue;
  }
  if (input.parentNode.closest('.multiInput') != null) {
    var obj = [];
    var parent = input.parentNode.closest('.multiInput');
    var children = parent.querySelectorAll('input,select');
    for (var i of children) {
      if (checkIfValueExist(i, i.type)) {
        obj[i.name] = i.value;
      }
    }
    multi[pos] = obj;
    results[parent.attributes.name.nodeValue] = multi;
    pos = pos + 1;
    iter = children.length-1;
  } else if (checkIfValueExist(input, input.type)) {
    results[input.name] = input.value;
    pos = 0;
    multi = [];
  }
}
return results;
}

function checkIfValueExist (target, type) {
  switch (type) {
    case 'text':
      return (target.value == "" ? false : true);
      break;
    case 'select-one':
      return (target.value == "" ? false : true);
      break;
    case 'checkbox':
      return (target.checked === false ? false : true);
      break;
    case 'radio':
      return (target.checked === false ? false : true);
      break;
    case 'button':
      return false;
      break;
    case 'submit':
      return false;
      break;
    default:
      return true;
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="ct">
  <input type="hidden" name="task" value="createTable"/>
  <div id="tableSection" class="flexContainer">
    <div class="block">
      <label for="dbName">Select Database</label>
      <select name="dbName" class="dbList" required>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Please Select</option>
        <option value="1">test</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <label for="tableName">Table Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="tableName" required/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row flexContainer multiInput" name="tableRow">
    <div class="trColumn">
      <label for="columnName">Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="columnName" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="trColumn">
      <label for="columnType">DataType</label>
      <select name="columnType" required>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Please Select</option>
        <option value="1">CHAR</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="trColumn">
      <label for="columnLength">Length</label>
      <input type="text" name="columnLength"/>
    </div>
    <div class="trColumn">
      <label for="columnPK">PK</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="columnPK" value="1"/>
    </div>
    <div class="trColumn">
      <label for="columnDefault">DefaultValue</label>
      <input type="text" name="columnDefault"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="button" class="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Result 1:

```
[task: "createDBTable", dbName: "1", tableName: "tester", tableRow: Array(1)]
dbName: "1"
tableName: "tester"
tableRow: [Array(0)]
task: "createDBTable"
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Result 2:

```
[task: "createDBTable", dbName: "1", tableName: "tester", tableRow: Array(1)]
    dbName: "1"
    tableName: "tester"
    tableRow: "[[]]"
    task: "createDBTable"
    length: 0
    __proto__: Array(0)
```

What I don't understand is why the tableRow is going from an `Array(6)` value to `[[]]` just because I setting the original variable, the returned value from the buildFormObject function, to a variable.

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**
In the code snippet above I have included the code I'm working with. There seems to be a small quirk where the console.log is only showing [], but you you type one of the property names that should be there like, "tableName"then you can access the value. This isn't true for the problem property of "tableRow" since the nested array is showing as `[]`. I'm not sure if it's the testing software, but if you try it on a local test environment then you shouldn't have any issues seeing what my initial problem is.

Comment: what does `buildFormObject` do? And what is `target`? It seems likely that this function performs some side effects - but you don't share its code, or any information about what it does.

Comment: That looks like PHP output, not JavaScript. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @RobinZigmond I'll add that function

Comment: @melpomene I formatted it so you could see the nested array in a way I thought would be easy to read but I've provided the console output code now.

Comment: `ReferenceError: target is not defined`

Comment: @melpomene you won't be able to run it. It order to run this I would have to post all the html and javascript on that page which isn't a small amount. The function is returning exactly what I'm expecting. The issue is what's happening after I get my expected results. I only posted function because Robin Zigmond requested it, which I assume is to check maybe the data types or things of that nature.

Comment: If I can't run it, it's not a [mcve]. If it's a lot of code, it's not a [mcve]. You're supposed to recreate the issue you're asking about (and only that issue) using as little code as possible. Otherwise your question just becomes "debug my web app for me" and will be closed.

Comment: Than I will have to rethink about how to ask it then

Comment: @melpomene I have added the most minimal code to get it working, but the tester isn't providing the same results as in a local environment. Not sure the cause, but if you use a local environment then you can definitely see the issue. It's pure html and javascript only.